# Удалить запись после определенного времени

Tags: mysql

Имеется табличка в `mysql`, в нее заносятся данные и их необходимо допустим через 2 часа удалить, каждое поле отдельно. Как это можно реализовать? т.е. указать что-то типо времени жизни записи

Comment: Посмотрите [это обсуждение][1]. Да и вообще, тема не раз поднималась на форуме.

   [1]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/206314/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привет, попробуй это

```
DELETE FROM base WHERE puttime < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR
```